# Transform and display cropped image in same orientation and dimension as reference image with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop, contour

I have a reference image and I am finding that reference image within a larger test image using ORB detection. Once found, I want to save ONLY the area within the crop as a new image. I'd like to transform it into the same dimensions as the reference image and save it in the same orientation.

So far I have matched the ref image in the larger image and have masked it out. But I cant figure out how to display ONLY the cropped area as its own picture, in the proper orientation and dimensions. I want to save whats in the crop and get rid of the rest of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#minimum ORB matches required to make a match
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img1 = cv2.imread("reference.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("1.jpg")

orb = cv2.ORB_create()
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1, des2, None)

# sorts matches
good = []
for i, m in enumerate(matches):
    if i < len(matches) - 1 and m.distance < 0.7 * matches[i+1].distance:
        good.append(m)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
    h,w,d = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
    mask = np.ones(img2.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(dst)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    new = cv2.drawContours(mask, [box], -1, 0, -1)
    # remove the contours from the image and show the resulting images
    img = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img2, mask=mask)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("After", img)
else:
    print( "Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT) )
    matchesMask = None

#This is for drawing the match lines inbetween the ref and 1.jpg images
draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
               singlePointColor = None,
               matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
               flags = 2)
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)
cv2.imshow("Matches", img3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track and already did most of the work. Since you have found the ROI mask, you can perform a perspective transform to get the correct orientation. Afterwards, you can resize the image to match your reference/template image.

First we invert the mask to get the desired ROI in white and then find contours on this mask. From here we find the corners using `cv2.arcLength()` and `cv2.approxPolyDP()`. Next we perspective transform to get this

[image]

```
template shape: (210, 236, 3)
transformed shape: (288, 279, 3)
```

Now that we have the correct orientation, we just need to simply resize to match the template image. Here's the result (left) and template image (right)

[image]
[image]

```
template shape: (210, 236, 3)
resized shape: (210, 236, 3)
```

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def perspective_transform(image, corners):
    def order_corner_points(corners):
        # Separate corners into individual points
        # Index 0 - top-right
        #       1 - top-left
        #       2 - bottom-left
        #       3 - bottom-right
        corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
        top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
        return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)

    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

#minimum ORB matches required to make a match
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img1 = cv2.imread("reference.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("1.jpg")

orb = cv2.ORB_create()
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1, des2, None)

# sorts matches
good = []
for i, m in enumerate(matches):
    if i < len(matches) - 1 and m.distance < 0.7 * matches[i+1].distance:
        good.append(m)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
    h,w,d = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
    mask = np.ones(img2.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(dst)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    new = cv2.drawContours(mask, [box], -1, 0, -1)
    # remove the contours from the image and show the resulting images
    img = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img2, mask=mask)
    mask = 255 - mask
    cv2.imshow("After", img)
else:
    print( "Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT) )
    matchesMask = None

#This is for drawing the match lines inbetween the ref and 1.jpg images
draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
               singlePointColor = None,
               matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
               flags = 2)
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)
cv2.imshow("Matches", img3)

cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

# Find contour on mask and perform perspective transform
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        transformed = perspective_transform(img2, approx)

cv2.imshow("transformed", transformed)

print('template shape:', img1.shape)
print('transformed shape:',transformed.shape)

resized = cv2.resize(transformed, (img1.shape[1], img1.shape[0]))
cv2.imshow("resized", resized)
print('template shape:', img1.shape)
print('resized shape:',resized.shape)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Wow! tysm nathancy. You made that look easy.

Comment: Currently, the resize using `cv2.resize()` does not maintain aspect ratio. If you want to maintain aspect ratio, look at [`imutils.resize()`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/convenience.py#L65). You may not get the exactly shape dimensions as the reference image though